# HTML5 Desktop notifications

Tags: html, notifications

I am dealing with desktop notifications on HTML5. My problem is on Firefox (on Chrome is fine), there I cann't throw more than 1 notification.

```
//Requestion permissions blablabla
if (permission === "granted") {
     var notification = new Notification(id, opt, null);
     var notification2 = new Notification(id, opt, null);
     var notification3 = new Notification(id, opt, null);
}
```

This doesn't work on Firefox, if I comment the last ones, works. 
Somebody know if I can do this

Comment: I just tested and I'm pretty sure ff only lets you show one at a time

Comment: On Chrome works nicely. On firefox I can display the same one several times (clicking on button). Thanks for trying, let me know if find out an answer

Comment: Why not use random tags? Set the tag to `"" + Math.random()` and you can show multiple notifications.

Answer (score 7):

Many aspects of displaying notifications are up to browsers, but in particular in this case you need to show more then one notification at the same time you can set a different "tag" attribute to each notification (http://www.w3.org/TR/notifications/#tags-example). If you don't specify a tag, the default one is used and the last notification "wins" over the previous ones.

Check this example:

```
<button id="authorize">Authorize notification</button>
<button id="show">Show notification</button>
<button id="show_another">Show another notification</button>

<script>
function authorizeNotification() {
    Notification.requestPermission(function(perm) {
        alert(perm);
    });
}
function showNotification(myTag) {
    var notification = new Notification("This is a title with tag " + myTag, {
        dir: "auto",
        lang: "",
        body: "This is a notification body with tag " + myTag,
        tag: myTag,
    });
}
document.querySelector("#authorize").onclick = authorizeNotification;
document.querySelector("#show").onclick = function(){ showNotification("firstTag"); };
document.querySelector("#show_another").onclick = function(){ showNotification("secondTag"); };
</script>
```

If you click "show notification" many times, the notification is closed and a new one is opened. Using the second button a new notification is shown without closing the old one.

You can find a working sample at JSFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/TuJHx/350/)

Comment: The problem is throwing at the same time, because if I change ids is still the problem

Comment: Can you post a working sample on JSFiddle so we can test it with real code?